# Select dropdown not generated via ng-repeat and ng-options

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angularjs-orderby

The two dropdowns below doesnt generate an array of years. I also need the years to be sorted from earliest to latest but the orderBy filter isnt working.

```
 <select title="- Select a period -" class="period " id="reportingPeriods">
        <option ng-repeat="reportingPeriod for reportingPeriod in reportingPeriods">{{reportingPeriod}}</option>
      </select>
      <br />
      <select title="- Select a period -" class="period selectpicker" id="" 
      ng-options="reportingPeriod for reportingPeriod in reportingPeriods | orderBy: '-reportingPeriod' ">
      </select>
```

Here is my javascript

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('ngrepeatSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    console.clear();
    $scope.data = {
     repeatSelect: null,
     availableOptions: [
       {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
       {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
       {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
     ],
    };

    $scope.reportingPeriods = [1999, 2011, 2000, 1988, 1995, 2014];
 }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Here is my [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mlxfD4IE2iK9XoR0gECX?p=preview)

Comment: `ng-options` requires `ng-model` too!

Comment: You are clearing the console which is hiding the error http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/ngRepeat/iidexp?p0=reportingPeriod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax for the ng-options and ng-repeat in the select options. Fixed here - http://plnkr.co/edit/oPI9kvQFuYJmrEwBDnWv?p=preview

Also you need to assign your ng-models to the select for them to work (as mentioned in the comments above by @AvijitGupta)

```
<select ng-model="period" title="- Select a period -" class="period " id="reportingPeriods">
    <option ng-repeat="reportingPeriod in reportingPeriods">{{reportingPeriod}}</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <select ng-model="preiod" title="- Select a period -" class="period selectpicker" id="" 
  ng-options="reportingPeriod for reportingPeriod in reportingPeriods | orderBy: '-' ">
  </select>
```

Comment: for your plunkr.. do you know why the orderBy isnt working at all?

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed, I'll take a look. Thanks for the info.

Comment: The expression was looking for the `reportingPeriod` attribute on the number values.  I've fixed both the plunkr and the answer above to reflect that.